# How to set dynamic viewTemplatePath in sails 1.0 using exits and actions2?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am trying to create an action that loads a view dynamically based on param passed in url

below is my `routes.js`

```
'GET faq/:alias': {actions:'faq'}
```

in my `faq` action

```
module.exports = {
    friendlyName: 'FAQ Pages',
    inputs: {
        alias: {
            description: 'the page url',
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    exits: {
        success: {
          statusCode: 200,
        },
        notFound: {
          responseType: 'notFound',
        }
    },
    fn: async function(inputs, exits) {
        console.log('static', inputs.alias);

        //something like this - set view tempalatePath
        //exits.success.viewTemplatePath = 'faqs/' + inputs.alias;
        //load view if exist else throw notFound

        return exits.success();
    }
};
```

All my faq's are in a folder, I will check if the physical file exists using `require('fs').existsSync()` and then load load it

Answer (score 0):

In the action2 format which you are using, you have to use `throw` to route to an alternate exit. See:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers

Do not be confused by the documentation here:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-view

... I don't know what it applies to, but it doesn't apply to action2's in 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while to figure out too, but below is best way I found to work.  In your faq action, change:

```
return exits.success();
```

to this:

```
return this.res.redirect('faq/' + inputs.alias);
```

**BACKGROUND:**
I notice in sails.js action2, when you use 'exits' where success responseType is defined as a 'view', it will not use the view-faq.js file at all, just skips directly to the faq.ejs page.  I'm using responseType 'redirect' to go to the view-faq.js first before loading the page.

If you do use responseType 'view' in your exits.success, you would need to add into your action the same code from fn: in your faq.js, and also send the page locals.  The problem I found with this method was an issue where the 'me' local somehow wasn't functioning properly with the new page view, which messed up my particular template.

Hope this saves someone else hours of time.